# When design networks using `caffe.NetSpec()`, how to know a certain blob shape?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

Let's say I am designing a network (e.g., upon Inception) using `caffe.Netspec()` as below.

```
import caffe
from caffe import layers as L

net          = caffe.NetSpec()
net.data     = ... 
net.label    = ...
net["conv1"] = L.convolution(...)
# ... concatenations ... and so on.
net["here"]  = ...
```

Is there a way to know the blob shape of any certain layer (e.g., layer `here`) like `7x7x128`?
I would like to make it until `1x1` shape, so I need to know which shape is so far.

Answer (score 0):

caffe.NetSpec() is used to initialize a net so that means you are defining the net on your own including the kernel sizes and other parameters like stride, padding. These parameters can be adjusted according to the size of the output you want for that particular layer. 
So knowing the blob size here doesn't arise since you are defining everything on your own.

In case you are loading a predefined net using caffe.Net() or caffe.SGDSolver(), then you can access the blobs by net.blobs.items(). 
You can try something like this:
[(k, v.data.shape) for k, v in solver.net.blobs.items()]

To get accustomed to the CAFFE net structure, you can have a look at the following example:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/01-learning-lenet.ipynb

This includes how a net is defined as well as how a net is loaded.